# Which files are deleted by Disk Cleanup's Temporary Files handler

Tags: windows, files

Windows Disk Cleanup offers a **Temporary Files** handler which seems to delete *some* files from C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp, but not all.  People around the place have indicated that it won't delete anything newer than one week, and I notice there are no old .tmp files hanging around afterwards.  So I guess it deletes only files ending in .tmp, and not in subdirectories, and only when a week old.  But I would like authoritative information.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by default it only cleans up files if they are older than 7 days old, but you can tweak that number to something else.

Taken [from here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36924/why-doesnt-disk-cleanup-delete-everything-from-the-temp-folder/):

> **Change Disk Cleanup to Delete Files Newer than 7 Days**
>
> If you’re one of
> those people that reboots your PC every day, you can probably change
> the Disk Cleanup value down to something lower, like 2 days. If you
> don’t reboot but you rarely keep applications open, you could probably
> do fine with 2-3 days instead, though the value you choose is really
> up to you—just keep in mind applications need those temporary files if
> they are running.
>
> Open up regedit.exe through the Start Menu search or run box, and then
> browse down to the following key:
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Files**
>
> Once you’re there, you’ll see the LastAccess value on the right-hand
> side, which contains a value that specifies the number of days, which
> you can change to whatever you’d like.
> [image]

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but I am hoping someone can tell me which files it will delete.